# Using model to save a list, works first time but second time it saves 62 count item list as 1 list item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I create this list in two different locations.  The first location creates it correctly its supposed to have 62 items in it like so.
[image]

But for some reason when I add it to the second PostSoftware action result I get the following with the exact same code.
[image]

The code is as follows

```
public ActionResult Software(TicketModel model)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Request software through the Tech Bar.";
            
            var snow = new clsServNowAuth();
            var tbl = clsServNowAuth.SoftwareTable();
            var tbl2 = clsServNowAuth.SoftwareTableID();
            tbl.Wait();
            tbl2.Wait();
            model.softwareList = tbl.Result;
            model.softwareListID = tbl2.Result;
            List<string> lstUserInfo = clsADInterface.GetInfo(model);
            List<string> softwareList = model.softwareList;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.computerName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.businessJustification))
            {
                // TODO
                return View(model);
            }
            
            return RedirectToAction("PostSoftware", model);
        }

        public ActionResult PostSoftware(TicketModel model)
        {
            List<string> softwareList = model.softwareList;
            //var test = model.selectedSoftwareList;
            List<string> softwareListID = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in model.selectedSoftwareList)
            {
                int index = softwareList.FindIndex(a => a.Contains(item));
                softwareListID.Add(model.softwareListID[index]);
            }
            // submit software request
            clsServNowAuth.SoftwareRequest(model.computerName, model.businessJustification, softwareListID, model.lstUserInfo);
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably need to show the code that builds the model in the html, and posts it back to the second endpoint.  Looks like you are calling `ToString()` somewhere (directly or indirectly) instead of iterating the list.

Comment: `model` is of type `TicketModel` in your first snippet too? Could you add the first methods signature, please?

Comment: @nilsK I fixed it so it shows the code right

Comment: I am not doing anything in the HTML with the models I think I need to define it as a list in the html too so it doesnt auto put as a string but not sure how to @Jonesopolis